# PHP Array logic re-factor

Tags: php, refactoring, arrays

## PHP Array logic re-factor

I'm trying to re-factor my code... This is PHP ...

I have the following:

```
$totals[] = "Total";
$totals[] = $counts['hole'][1] + $counts['warn'][1] + $counts['info'][1] + $counts['crit'][1];
$totals[] = $counts['hole'][2] + $counts['warn'][2] + $counts['info'][2] + $counts['crit'][2];
$totals[] = $counts['hole'][3] + $counts['warn'][3] + $counts['info'][3] + $counts['crit'][3];
$totals[] = $counts['hole'][4] + $counts['warn'][4] + $counts['info'][4] + $counts['crit'][4];
$totals[] = $counts['hole'][5] + $counts['warn'][5] + $counts['info'][5] + $counts['crit'][5];
$totals[] = $counts['hole'][6] + $counts['warn'][6] + $counts['info'][6] + $counts['crit'][6];
```

---

Why doesn't this work?

```
for($i; $i < 6; $i++ ){
    foreach( $severity as $sev ){
        $totals[$i] = $totals[$i] + $counts[$sev][$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in the for loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    foreach ($severity as $sev) {
        $totals[$i] += $counts[$sev][$i];
    }
}
```

You forgot to initialize the `$i` variable.

Comment: Yes, I did forget to initialize the $i var... This caused undesired results because all of this was inside another foreach loop.  I also adjusted the code to reflect the += ... I have not used php in a while and wasn't sure if that sytax was allowed.  (I'm a python hacker normally).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The indices run from 1 to 6 (inclusive), so the `for` loop should be like

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++ ){
   ....
```

BTW, you could use

```
$totals[$i] += $counts[$sev][$i];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  you were spot on correct and your input was helpful, however I read 'Alix Axel' answer first.

Answer (score 0):

[`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) is pretty useful in these scenarios

```
foreach( range(1,6) as $i ){
    foreach( $severity as $sev ){
        $totals[$i] += $counts[$sev][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach` is faster and prettier but `range` uses more memory, specially on large ranges.

Comment: @Alix, `range(1,6)` is not large. No need to optimize it past that.